# how to sum values ​of arrays in the same position

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this line of code, how could I add the // "0[37][16]" to total 53 for example?

```
updateTotalMedidas() {
    this.ɵcart.medidaTotal = 0;
    for (const item of this.ɵcart.item) {
      let row_cm = (item.medidas[0] * item.medidas[1] * item.medidas[2]) * item.quantidade; // (3) [84, 40, 15] and (3) [30, 18, 8]
      let totalCmCubico = row_cm  // 50400 and 4320
      let raiz_cubica =  Math.round(Math.cbrt(totalCmCubico))  // 37 and  16
      this.ɵcart.medidaTotal += JSON.stringify([raiz_cubica]); // "0[37][16]"

    }
  }
```

if I remove the "[]" from this.ɵcart.medidaTotal it becomes 3716, so I put the [], but I don't understand why it stays in that format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you put everything inside `JSON.stringify` this converts objects into JSON strings. So in your current code `mediaTotal` will be first 0 then "37" and at last "3716". No need for that in your code.

You can just do this, because `raiz_cubica` is a number.

```js
this.ɵcart.medidaTotal += raiz_cubica;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it worked

Comment: how could i make the sum of the let totalCmCubico = row_cm // 50400 and 4320

Comment: it is returning the error
 Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'row_cm'.

Comment: I don't have enough informatiom from your code to help you, make a new question if you need more help.